# AndroidAnnotations 3.0 @Rest

Tags: java, android, android-annotations

I am trying to access a REST API using AndroidAnnotations. My code is as follows:

```
public interface MyRestInterface
{
    //for some reason it is not possible to specify MultiValueMap<String, Object> -
    //annotations produce invalid code
    @Post("/rest.api")
    public ResponseEntity<MyXMLResponse> makeRequest(MultiValueMap multiValueMap);
}
```

On AA version 2.7.1 this produced the following code:

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<TravelAbroadIssuePolicyXmlResponse> makeRequest(MultiValueMap multiValueMap) 
{
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap> requestEntity = new  HttpEntity<MultiValueMap>(multiValueMap, httpHeaders);
    return restTemplate.exchange(rootUrl.concat("/rest.api"), HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, MyXMLResponse.class);
}
```

That was working as intended, specifically it was putting the MultiValueMap values into the body of the request.
However, with AA 3.0, it produced this:

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<MyXMLResponse> makeRequest(MultiValueMap multiValueMap) 
{
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap>(multiValueMap);
    ... (try to make a request and intercept errors)
}
```

Note that the HTTP headers are not involved anymore. Oddly, this results in the fact that the MultiValueMap values are put into the request headers, leaving the body empty. 
For the time being, I resorted to using AA 2.7.1. Is there a correct way to do it on AA 3.0+?

Answer (score 0):

As you're using a `MultiValueMap` class, I suppose that your rest client has to call a form HTTP ws. So you have to use `FormHttpMessageConverter` as converter for the request. Could you confirm you're using this one ?

Also, you should update to AA 3.0.1 which solves generics usage.